# Where does `multirust` install the Rust language source code?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I installed the `multirust` version of the Rust programming language. I was trying to configure the `racer` code completion package to point to the Rust source code through the `RUST_SRC_PATH`environment variable. However, I can't seem to find the location of the rust source files. When I type `which rustc` I am pointed to `/usr/local/bin` probably because there is a symlink to the actual source directory or something. Any info on where the proper directory for the `RUST_SRC_PATH` variable is for `multirust`?

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/local/bin/rustc` tell you?

Comment: It tells me: ` ls -l /usr/local/bin/rustc      -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2889 Nov 24 13:24 /usr/local/bin/rustc`

Comment: There is a `~/.multirust/toolchains/stable/bin` folder in my home directory. Would that be the correct one to use. There is a `rustc` and a `cargo` file in there.

Comment: Re: your first comment, that means that it's not a symlink. The `.multirust` directory does sound promising.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, [multirust doesn't install the source](https://github.com/brson/multirust/issues/77). This is also [mentioned in the context of using racer with multirust](https://github.com/brson/multirust/issues/114).

Instead, follow the [instructions in the Racer README](https://github.com/phildawes/racer):

> Fetch the Rust sourcecode from git, or download from https://www.rust-lang.org/install.html

Comment: Okay interesting. So I am a little confused because I had installed rust using the rustup.sh script initially. Then when I installed multirust, the installer asked me to uninstall the previous version of rust. So I uninstalled the rustup.sh version of rust. But you are saying that multirust does not install the source? So I am just trying to understand where I should be looking or something. Am I missing something?

Comment: Here is the specific notation from the multirust github site indicating that I need to uninstall any previously installed rust version. "Installation of multirust over an existing installation of Rust or vice versa will cause brokenness. Uninstall the other first. ./install.sh will detect this and error. This should be fixable in the future." Any clarification would be appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: @krishnab To my knowledge, none of the official Rust installers (which is what `rustup.sh` runs) include the Rust source. The issue I linked shows that multirust does not install the Rust source. [The README for Racer says](https://github.com/phildawes/racer) " Fetch the rust sourcecode from git, or download from https://www.rust-lang.org/install.html ".

Comment: Okay got you. So I used git to download the rust src and then used that for the environment variable. I will note this on the stackexchange answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 14):

By default, rustup doesn't install the source code for the Rust standard library. But you can execute the following command to install it:

```
$ rustup component add rust-src
```

The source is installed in `~/.rustup/toolchains/$TOOLCHAIN/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/` (where `$TOOLCHAIN` is the name of a toolchain you use).