# Cargo path setup for rust-racer

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I just installed `racer` using `cargo`. After installing it say this:

```
Installing /home/karthik/.cargo/bin/racer
warning: be sure to add `/home/karthik/.cargo/bin` to your PATH to be able to run the installed binaries
```

How do I do this? Googling didn't help. Also, Should I be setting a `PATH` variable for cargo bin as well?

Edit: OS is Ubuntu 14.04 and I have super user access

Comment: Please add more information like your OS, do you launch in command line? In command line mode you just have to type export PATH=$PATH:/home/karthik/.cargo/bin and hit Enter. Then type your command to run your program

Comment: Ok, I've done that, now how do I set Racer's path? I've cloned rust's src code and set the Rust src path

Comment: Ok, I have a new problem. For racer I did export PATH=$PATH:/home/karthik/.cargo/bin/racer. The nfor the rust src path I did export RUST_SRC_PATH=/usr/local/src/rust/src. This works and I can use racer (and it works in vim with YouCompleteMe). But it doesn't work in any other terminal instance and if I close the terminal I did it in, it still doesn't work anywhere

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add the cargo bin path to your `PATH` variable and set the `RUST_SRC_PATH` in `.profile` or `.bash_profile`.

[Related unix.stackechange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps:

(1) Add the Cargo bin to your `PATH` variable.  You can run `$ whereis cargo` to find the bin path, and then do `$ sudo -H gedit /etc/environment` where you can add that new path section to your current `PATH` variable.  You will need to save and close the file (and you can ignore the error message in the terminal during the saving portion) in order for it to take effect.

(2) Run `$ rustup component add rust-src` to download the necessary Rust source files for you.

At this point Racer should work properly.

This is based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33901423/where-does-multirust-install-the-rust-language-source-code).